# How do I install PHP PDO ODBC drivers on CentOS 7?

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I already have PHP 5.4 installed in a CentOS 7 VPS. I am trying now to access a legacy database in **.mdb** format with a PHP script.

However, my **phpinfo()** page says that only `mysql` and `sqlite` PDO drivers are enabled. No driver named ODBC is enabled.

Which is why I have tried to follow [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php) tutorial to get that to work. But it doesn't work. `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.

I don't know from which folder I have to run the commands listed there. Is there a command which will allow me to install the PDO ODBC drivers from the system e.g. `yum -y install php_odbc` which would be easier for me to work with? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910255/plesk-12-on-centos-6-not-working-pdo-odbc-dblib-drivers ). I think it should solve your issue.

Comment: It solved my problem: yum install php-pdo

Comment: What you link as a tutorial relates to the PHP source distribution, you need to obtain the sources first if you like to compile the extension your own (configure is a step prior compilation and part of a common build flow).

Answer (score 9):

Looks like `php_odbc` is one of **CentOS** 7 packages.
See http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ it is a very long list.

So `yum -y install php_odbc` should work. Just don't forget to restart your web-server if required.

You would run `./configure ...` if you were compiling PHP from source. It will not work in your case.

Comment: yum -y install php-odbc #worked on our device. php_odbc failed.